# Update single character in mysql field

Tags: mysql, replace, field

I have a column dedicated to keeping track of which messages on my project were viewed. It's written like "10010", a 1 denoting that the message has been seen and also without making it into many different columns. But how do I make one database call to replace just the 3rd character, or the 5th character in the field? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use SUBSTRING and CONCAT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment was right. If you want more informations you can go there :

[Change a character in a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461616/change-the-first-character-in-a-field)

You just have to change some things (in your project, you don't want to change the first character)